# Why does = not seem to be working in script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.6

Below is the script I am working with. However, I get N/A for values which should have a statement as the output. I have added the screenshot showing the N/A that the script produces instead of the statement.

```
def reclass (tmin_13D):
    if tmin_13D >= 4:
        return "Frost free"
    elif tmin_13D <= 0:
        return "High frost risk"
    elif 2 < tmin_13D <= 3:
        return "Low frost risk"
    elif 0 < tmin_13D <= 2:
        return "Moderate frost risk"
    else:
        return "N/A"
```

Expression: reclass (!tmin_13D!)

[image]

Comment: Is your tmin_13D column truly an integer or double? Or is it a string?

Comment: Hi. It is a double

Comment: I changed to integer and it worked! No more N/A, many thanks!

Comment: @KHibma Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the field you're using to compare is actually a number (not a string).

"4" > 4 is not the same as 4 > 4. If your compare value is a string, your logic will fall down into the *else* part of your code.